Helper Library for CMake Project
I am new to CMake so my issue is probably simple to solve. I have the following project structure:
Project Root
CMakeLists.txt
    |---- Library/Executable A
    |     | .c and .h files
    |     |---- CMakeLists.txt
    |---- Library/Executable B
    |     | .c and .h files
    |     |---- CMakeLists.txt
    |---- Library C
    |     | .c and .h files
    |     |---- CMakeLists.txt
    

For Debug purposes I have a main in each sub-project that I use. The exception being Library C that is a collection of helper functions and data structures, mostly contained in header-only files. Library C is using in multiple points in the project, sometimes more than once in a single sub-project.
I am running into an issue of "already defined" objects when I build. I want to use the helper library where it is needed, but have it not conflict when I am using multiple sub-projects that use it independently. How would I go about configuring the CMakeLists.txt to account for this?
Library C is added as an interface:
add_library(lib_c INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(lib_c "PATH_TO_HEADER_DIRECTORY")

Each header has the requisite header guards:
#ifndef HEADER_NAME_H
#define HEADER_NAME_H
...
#endif


At a guess, your header files probably lack header guards.

Every header has the
#define HEADER_NAME_H 
...
#endif``` 
in them. This includes `Library C`.

Please give us a command-line used for one of the failing compilations, and the exact error message, so we can better understand what's going on. It may be that @JesperJuhl's guess is valid - but we can't tell.

The problem is most likely caused by something wrong in the code and nothing you can do in CMakeLists.txt.

Side note: C & C++ are very different languages. Unless your question is about the interaction between them or similar, you should generally not tag both. Tag only the language you are actually using.

I am using both C and C++. Library A is all C, and Library B is C++, but uses Library A.
The command-line error I get is: LNK2005 cubeVerts already defined in render_main.cpp.obj
And cubeVerts is defined in the header only library as:
float cubeVerts[] = {
 -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,     0.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f, // 0 - bottom left
  ...
 -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.5f,     1.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f, // 7 - top left

};


Header guards don't solve the problem of defining a variable in a header that is used by more than 1 source file. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51612866/global-variables-in-header-only-library

@Senuska Well there you have it, a definition of cubeVert in a header file. Hence the multiple definitions. Just move the definition to a cpp file and replace with a declaration (i.e. extern float cubeVerts[];) in the header file. Nothing to do with cmake (as already mentioned).
